# Is it possible to use a different pattern in a velocity template for variable substitution

Tags: variables, velocity, vtl

I have many text files I want to use as a velocity template but the actual notation for the variable is : {my_variable_x}.

In Velocity template by defaut it will be like this: $my_variable_x

Is there a way to configure velocity to use a different notation than the classic $variable?

I read the user's guide and developer's guide but did not find anything related to my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no easy way of doing that other than checking out [the sources](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/velocity/), changing [the grammar file](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/velocity/engine/trunk/velocity-engine-core/src/main/parser/Parser.jjt), [building](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/devel/build.html) the modified engine, and deploying the resulting custom jar.

Comment: Ok it is overkill for what we want, a linux sed command will transform the source templates to velocity. Thanks anyway for your answer.